# How to move/center the linear transformation of the plane?

Tags: python, animation, matrix, vector, manim

I'm new in Manim and I'm trying to scale my plane because the grid and vectors get out under the following linear transformation

```
class LinearTransformationSceneExample(LinearTransformationScene):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
            *kwargs
        )

    def construct(self):
        matrix = [[9, 0], [-3/2, 3/2]]
        self.apply_matrix(matrix)
        self.wait()
```

I tried many things, but withput any success. However, the closest I have come has been with the following code, but the linear transformation is applied in the  center of the plane

```
class LinearTransformationSceneExample(LinearTransformationScene):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        LinearTransformationScene.__init__(
            self,
            show_coordinates=True,
            leave_ghost_vectors=True,
            background_plane_kwargs = {
            "x_range" : [-10,10],
            "y_range" : [-1,10],
            "x_length" : 14.2,
            "y_length" : 8
            },
            foreground_plane_kwargs = {
            "x_range" : [-10,10],
            "y_range" : [-1,10],
            "x_length" : 14.2,
            "y_length" : 8
            }
        )

    def construct(self):
        vec = Vector([-1,1])
        vec.set_color(PURPLE)
        self.add_vector(vec)
      
        matrix = [[9, 0], [-3/2, 3/2]]
        self.apply_matrix(matrix)
        self.wait()
```

If you can follow the idea of the code above it'd be great, but it's not really necessary